# Changing the size of a button within revolution slider

Tags: html, css

I have made a button within Revolution slider, that enables users to click the button to scroll down to the next section on the site.

However I am un-able to change the size of the button.

I am aware that it says "small" and I have tried changing this to "medium", but this does not change the size of the button.

Below is the code, thanks for any help!

```
<a onclick="scrollWin()" style="position:relative;" class='tp-button blue small'>    
   Scroll Down

   <script>     
   function scrollWin() {    
      window.scrollBy(0, 900);    
   }
   </script>
</a>
```

Comment: write into style tag width:100px;height:75px;

Comment: I don't know the Revolution slider features but if you remove the small class without replace it?

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your reply unfortunately these changes did not work.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have the `tp-button` and `small` css code?

Comment: Have you try to use both the suggestions at the same time?

Comment: Amazing that is now working, last little bit how could I increase the text size in the situation?

Comment: I think you only have to put in style attribute the `font-size` rule and set it to the value you prefer